# Are there any advantages when competing in a raid at a friendly gym?

Tags: pokemon-go

I opened up Pokémon Go to see if there were any raids in my area, and to my surprise there were multiple going on. One of the raids was occurring at a gym controlled by Mystic and the other gym was controlled by Valor.

[image]
[image]

As any player of any team can participate in any raid, even ones controlled by other teams, are there any advantages when competing in a raid located at a gym that is controlled by a friendly team?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After defeating the Pokemon, you get a limited number of special poke balls (Premier Balls) to try to catch it. The number of balls you get is based on several factors, including team control of the gym.

So yes, winning a raid battle at a friendly gym gives you more chances to attempt to catch the Pokemon after winning than a gym controlled by another team.

Here are two screenshots after defeating a raid boss solo on a Mystic-controlled gym. The first is by an Instinct player; the second is Mystic.

[image: raidbattlerewards] [image: gymcontrolbonus]

Comment: I've only done one raid so far, so there may be other benefits I missed or am forgetting

Comment: "Based on several factors, including team control of the gym". Can you provide a source for that? It's not much to go on if you've one done one raid. I've only done one, with it being friendly, and I got 14 premier

Comment: I've also seen this happen, and I'm sure I've seen it mentioned on The Silph Road, but don't have a source offhand unfortunately

Comment: I'll try to get a screenshot of the math after my next raid. Or, if anyone else manages to get one, feel free to edit it into the answer

Comment: @RCaetano Thanks for adding the screenshot. Where did you get the name "Premier Balls"? I didn't notice that mentioned anywhere.

Comment: @yoozer8 Here you will some of the aspects you mentioned before :) http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/raidbattles.shtml

Comment: @yoozer8 the picture that was added by RCaetano provides good info. Premier balls are in the main game series, and it's also name on [Niantic's website](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/115009004747-Raid-Battles). *You’ll also receive a number of Premier Balls used for catching the Raid Boss.*

Comment: I've won two raids on gyms controlled by Mystic (that I also had a Pokémon in), but I've gotten +0 for Gym Control both times, so I'm not really sure what that bonus is for.

Comment: I just completed a raid where I did get a gym controlled bonus. The gym is controlled by my team, I have a Pokemon there, and I was the only one on this raid. Got a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYS3a.jpg) of the summary.

Comment: @yoozer8 and Vemonus so maybe we can deduce that we will only win that bonus if we have one of our Pokémon in the gym? If someone have more info supporting this share please :)

Comment: @RCaetano I had Pokémon in both gyms when I beat the raid bosses, but didn't get the extra premier balls. I have seen reports by other users saying that it appears that the bonus isn't awarded if the team switches control while the raid is "about to start", so that might be it.