# How can I receive the maximum number of premier balls?

Tags: pokemon-go

Per my [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/311826/are-there-any-advantages-when-competing-in-a-raid-at-a-friendly-gym), the answer provided contains a screen shot of a post-boss summary and obtaining a number of premier balls to capture the raid boss.

[image]

There are various bonuses that go towards primer balls, in which case this totaled to 11. When I did a raid, the number of premier balls I received as 14.

What are all of the bonuses that go towards obtaining premier balls, and how can I maximize each bonus to receive the highest amount premier balls?

Comment: Charge your phone.

Comment: @Avery It's not my phone :) Image was provided by another user in my linked question

Comment: They should charge their phones.

Comment: Niantic really needs to work on the battery usage...

Comment: They really do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [PokemonGo Hub](https://pokemongohub.net/post/breaking-news/0-67-1-data-mine-part-ii-battle-teams-bonus-gym-loot-badge-map/), a data mine revealed that the following influence how many Premier Balls you receive:

> - The base Pokeballs
> - Your damage contribution
> - Team Damage contribution
> - Gym Ownership
> - The percentage of damage inflicted by your team

All of these seems to hold true based off the screenshot in your picture. [One source](https://pokemongohub.net/gym-raid-update/premier-ball/) suggests that the level of your Gym Badge with the gym influences how many you can receive as well.

The [Silph Road Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/6ihl5t/the_silph_roads_apk_mine_of_v0671_is_complete_15/) seems to agree with this list, and states the same, with the addition of a currently unknown multiplier:

> In a Raid, you appear to be awarded more 'Premier Balls' based on a
>   few factors. These include:
>
> - The base Pokeballs
> - Individual damage contribution
> - Team Damage contribution
> - Gym Ownership
> - The percentage of damage inflicted by your team
> - A 'Bonus Item Multiplier' (unclear at the time of publication)

I think it's pretty self explanatory on how to receive more premier balls.  Basically, do as much damage as you can, your team has to do as much damage as they can, and try and do Raids in Gyms that are controlled by your team.

Answer (score -2):

Damage contribution is one that you can influence by fighting with smaller teams I think.
Suppose you succeed a raid with a team of 10 then your contribution will more or less be 10% if equally spread.
Succeeding with a team of 20 will be 5% and thus your damage will decrease and the amount of balls as well.

Comment: This doesn't add anything new. *Individual damage contribution* has already been mentioned in the accepted answer